# Calling a method that is usually called with KeyPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, accelerometer, motion, shake

I am using [shake.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/) and I am modifying a game. The avatar jumps fine with button press but with the shake it jumps once and refuses to jump more. I am sure that the shake event is still firing because I can get the alert to pop up. Anybody have any idea what is happening inside of the shake action that is different than that for the keypress? Thank you!

```
var handleJump = function(pressed) {
                if (g_jump != pressed) {
                    g_jump = pressed;
                    g_client.sendCmd('jump', {
                        jump: pressed,
                    });
                }
            };

            //listen to shake event
           var shakeEvent = new Shake({threshold: 10});
                      shakeEvent.start();
                      window.addEventListener('shake', function(){
                        alert('shake!')
                        handleJump(true);
                      }, false);
                      function stopShake(){
                          shakeEvent.stop();
                      }

            var keys = {};
            keys[Input.cursorKeys.kLeft] = function(e) {
                handleLeftRight(e.pressed, 0x1);
            }
            keys[Input.cursorKeys.kRight] = function(e) {
                handleLeftRight(e.pressed, 0x2);
            }
            keys["Z".charCodeAt(0)] = function(e) {
                handleJump(e.pressed);
            }
            Input.setupKeys(keys);

            Touch.setupButtons({
                inputElement: $("buttons"),
                buttons: [{
                    element: $("left"),
                    callback: function(e) {
                        handleLeftRight(e.pressed, 0x1);
                    },
                }, {
                    element: $("right"),
                    callback: function(e) {
                        handleLeftRight(e.pressed, 0x2);
                    },
                }, {
                    element: $("up"),
                    callback: function(e) {
                        handleJump(e.pressed);
                    },
                }, ],
            });
        };
```